# Tomar Posicion geográfica sin estar conectado a wifi o datos

Tags: android-studio

Buenas tardes muchachos, quisiera me pudieran colaborar con un inconvenienten que tengo en Android; tengo un App que toma las coordenadas geográficas y lo hace bien mientras está conectada a wifi o datos de plan, pero cuando me desconecto de Internet ya no se capturan las coordenadas y el GPS permanece activado, por otra parte se pone bastante lenta la aplicación, aquí el código que uso, quizá me puedan ayudar optimizando mi proceso, de ante mano muchas gracias!

```
public class Localizacion implements LocationListener {
        MainActivity mainActivity;

        public MainActivity getMainActivity() {
            return mainActivity;
        }

        public void setMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity) {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que el GPS recibe nuevas coordenadas
            // debido a la deteccion de un cambio de ubicacion
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();
           /* String Text = "Mi ubicacion actual es: " + "\n Lat = "
                    + loc.getLatitude() + "\n Long = " + loc.getLongitude();*/
//            mensaje1.setText(Text);
            this.mainActivity.setLocation(loc);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es desactivado
//            mensaje1.setText("GPS Desactivado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cuando el GPS es activado
//            mensaje1.setText("GPS Activado");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // Este metodo se ejecuta cada vez que se detecta un cambio en el
            // status del proveedor de localizacion (GPS)
            // Los diferentes Status son:
            // OUT_OF_SERVICE -> Si el proveedor esta fuera de servicio
            // TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE -> Temporalmente no disponible pero se
            // espera que este disponible en breve
            // AVAILABLE -> Disponible
        }

    }/* Fin de la clase localizacion */
```

En la Clase MainActivity tengo este método:

```
public void setLocation(Location loc) {
        //Obtener la direccion de la calle a partir de la latitud y la longitud
        if (loc.getLatitude() != 0.0 && loc.getLongitude() != 0.0) {
            try {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                lat = loc.getLatitude() + "";
                lng = loc.getLongitude() + "";
                if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                    Address DirCalle = list.get(0);
                  /*  mensaje2.setText("Mi direccion es: \n"
                            + DirCalle.getAddressLine(0));*/
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

y Empiezo a capturar las coordenadas así en el Oncreate:

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MainActivity.Localizacion Local = new MainActivity.Localizacion();
        Local.setMainActivity(this);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, (LocationListener) Local);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te adjunto el codigo que utilizo para obtener la geolocalizacion desde android :

Clase GPSTracker

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    // Get Class Name
    private static String TAG = GPSTracker.class.getName();

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS Tracking is enabled
    boolean isGPSTrackingEnabled = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // How many Geocoder should return our GPSTracker
    int geocoderMaxResults = 1;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    // Store LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER or LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER information
    private String provider_info;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Try to get my current location by GPS or Network Provider
     */
    public void getLocation() {

        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            // Try to get location if you GPS Service is enabled
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use GPS Service");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location using
                 * satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return
                 * a location fix.
                 */

                provider_info = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;

            } else if (isNetworkEnabled) { // Try to get location if you Network Service is enabled
                this.isGPSTrackingEnabled = true;

                Log.d(TAG, "Application use Network State to get GPS coordinates");

                /*
                 * This provider determines location based on
                 * availability of cell tower and WiFi access points. Results are retrieved
                 * by means of a network lookup.
                 */
                provider_info = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            }

            // Application can use GPS or Network Provider
            if (!provider_info.isEmpty()) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        provider_info,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
                        this
                );

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider_info);
                    updateGPSCoordinates();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update GPSTracker latitude and longitude
     */
    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker latitude getter and setter
     * @return latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker longitude getter and setter
     * @return
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * GPSTracker isGPSTrackingEnabled getter.
     * Check GPS/wifi is enabled
     */
    public boolean getIsGPSTrackingEnabled() {

        return this.isGPSTrackingEnabled;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this method will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        //Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("titulo");

        //Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Settings");

        //On Pressing Setting button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("positiveButton", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //On pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("cancelButton", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
     * @return null or List<Address>
     */
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
        if (location != null) {

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);

            try {
                /**
                 * Geocoder.getFromLocation - Returns an array of Addresses
                 * that are known to describe the area immediately surrounding the given latitude and longitude.
                 */
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, this.geocoderMaxResults);

                return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);

        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Su forma de llamarlo :

```
    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
    if(gpsTracker.isGPSTrackingEnabled)
    {
        double latitud = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
        double longitud = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
    }
    else
    {
        gpsTracker.showSettingsAlert();
    }
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda

Saludos.

Comment: Excelente amigo me funcionó!, muchas gracias